# Get Perspective Distance

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry, image-processing

My goal is to detect a tennis court from an image. I already preprocessed the image such that I know the base-line. I also have candidate corner points. I know the focal point of the image. And I know the angles α and β.

How do I find out which points (here in red) are the correct ones, when knowing they should be 18ft from the base line.

[image: Diagram]

Comment: Is $27$ the base of the triangle? If so it seems a simple trigonometric problem. Do you know how to find the other two sides of the triangle?

Comment: 27 is the base (actually the 4.5ft are not relevant for this.). The 18ft are in perspective. For me it is not obvious how I could solve it with trigonometry. The blue lines are also known.